# Не работает ф-я подкл к БД при частом её вызове

Tags: sql, golang

Добрый день. Есть функция для работы с БД

```
func new_query_select(Query string, args ...interface{}) []mysql.Row{
    db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "password", "test")
    err := db.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")
    }
    rows, _, err := db.Query(Query,args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос",Query)
    }
    return rows
}
```

В других функциях я формирую sql и передаю в эту выполняющую функцию. 
Возможно Вы скажете- это корявый вариант, но всё-же если идти по этому пути- я столкнулся с проблемой, когда начал имитировать большое количество запросов и вызывать эту функцию - мне выдало исключение, "Не удалось выполнить запрос".
На сколько я понял-одна из функций приложения обратилась к этой функции(new_query_select) когда она работала с БД, потому что, если запросы идут редко-то всё нормально. Как только начинаю слать, скажем 10-15 запросов в секунду, что-то происходит и после этого уже никакой другой запрос не работает и переходит в исключение "Не удалось выполнить запрос".

Вопрос: Что делать, что-б не было этого глюка? Может его в горутину поместить или что можно сделать?

Comment: Забыл написать defer db.Close() - Вроде сейчас нормально стало- пока не вылетало исключение. Если у кого-то есть идеи или подсказки- напишите, как делать нормально...))

Comment: Ну так может если `if err != nil {` то и выводить `err`, чтобы понимать что за ошибка?

Comment: log.Println(err.Error)   выдал - 0x415e00 . Но если с defer db.Close() , то этого не было. Вообщем, на сколько я понял- он не позакрывал соединения и у него закипел мозг от такого количества...

Comment: Вероятнее всего так и есть.

Comment: Золотое правило: _одно соединение - много запросов_.

Comment: Вопрос хороший, годный. Многим может помочь. Но я бы посоветовал добавить "sql-ных" тэгов и изменить название самого вопроса (чтоб легче было тематически его найти). Например "Интенсивные запросы к БД приводят к исключениям".

Comment: @RakzinRoman Вы забыли вызвать метод: `log.Println(err.Error())`.

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из кода, видим следующее:

*10-15 запросов в секунду* = 10-15 установлений **новых соединений** с базой,
что является огромным оверхедом, расточительным использованием ресурсов и совершенно неприемлемой архитектурой кода.

На установление каждого (!) соединения может требоваться до 2Мб памяти и какое-то время (в секундах или миллисекундах, в зависимости от операционной доступности сервера). В итоге получается страшный "затык". Кроме того, я уверен, что сама база вполне может рубить такое количество соединений.

Нормальная практика программирования - выполнять запросы (Query, Execute) к базе поверх лишь **одного** поднятого соединения (Connection) которое следует поддерживать в активном состоянии на период "жизни" формы или страницы. Иными словами, надо сначала создать ОДНО соединение к базе, а потом использовать его во всех запросах.

Сематнтически (без привязки к какому либо языку программирования) это должно выглядеть вот так:

```
ConnectionObj = New(Connection) // создали соединение с БД

//начинаем интенсивно использовать единственное и достаточное соединение
//для выполнения кучи запросов:

//пример использования для возврата датасета 
DataSet = ConnectionObj.Query('SELECT * FROM Users') 

//пример использования без возврата датасета 
ConnectionObj.Execute('DROP TABLE Users') 

//Выполнили свои задачи, наигрались, закрываем соединение и уничтожаем объект

ConnectionObj.Close
ConnectionObj.Free // или = nil, null, и т.д.
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже посоветовали - необходимо изменить способ работы с БД: в функции main или init создавать подключение к базе и потом использовать его.

Примерный код [здесь](http://play.golang.org/p/MVkKBvM76p)